# GitHub organization deploy key

Tags: github

I recently migrated from Bitbucket to a Github account in my department.

In Bitbucket, I can create a team deploy key and use it across all projects.

In Github I couldn't find this option. I found that I must create a "machine user" and add it to my team. This seems a little jerry-rig and I would also lose a team seat.

How to overcome this and create an organization-level deploy key?

EDIT: I have two servers that use 3 repositories each. I want to be able to deploy the 3 repositories in both servers.

Comment: You can't create an organization-level deploy key, but if you describe specifically what kind of setup you have, why you might need such a deploy key, someone might be able to suggest a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @dave Edited question.

Comment: I think you're stuck with the machine user solution. It may seem like a jerry-rig but it's the official GitHub supported way of doing things. 

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys